# Getting finished with status code: 204 on Firebase Function and nothings happened

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am developing a function to send email to customers.

```
exports.sendRestockingNotification = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  try {
    console.log("Sending confirmation email to the customer...");
    sendEmailRestocking(data.numero, data.nombre, data.emails);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unexpected error: ", error);
  }
});

function sendEmailRestocking (numero, nombre, emails) {
  console.log("Sending Email...");
    return transport.sendMail({
      from: "XXXXX <xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
      to: emails,
      subject: "El artículo " + nombre + " (" + numero + ") vuelve a estar disponible.",
      html: 
            `
            <div class="container rounded"  style="padding: 10px 30px;">
                <div class="container rounded" style="background-color: #0bbe83;">
                    <h1 style="color: white; padding: 5px;">TejidosPulido</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="padding: 10px 50px;">
                    <h5 style="color: #0bbe83;">Hola, </h5>
                    <p>
                        El artículo ${nombre} (${numero}) vuelve a estar disponible. ¡Date prisa antes de que se termine!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p style="padding: 10px 30px;"> 
                    Un saludo,
                    <br>
                    Tu equipo TejidosPulido
                </p>
            </div>
          `,
    });
}
```

But I am always getting the same in the Firebase Functions console and any mail is sent and the debug message `console.log("Sending a confirmation email to the customer...");` is not showed neither:

**sendRestockingNotification ->** Function execution started

**sendRestockingNotification ->** Function execution took 14 ms, finished with status code: 204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the doc for [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). You need to return data that can be JSON encoded.

So you need to wait for the asynchronous `sendEmailRestocking()` function to terminate before sending a response. For example with the following adaptations:

```
exports.sendRestockingNotification = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {  // See async
  try {
    console.log("Sending confirmation email to the customer...");
    await sendEmailRestocking(data.numero, data.nombre, data.emails);
    return {result: "mail send"}; // For example
  } catch (error) {
    // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    console.error("Unexpected error: ", error);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried the first one and I get also the same 204 code

Comment: I have found the bug. It was a mistake on the client-side because of a reload page before the function finished...